# Retaining recipient address when forwarding using postfix

Tags: email, postfix, mail-forwarding

I'm setting up postfix to forward e-mails sent to a domain to outside e-mail addresses. i.e. when I get an e-mail at philip@contoso.com it gets sent automatically to philip@example.com. That's working except that when I receive the e-mail it shows the recipient at philip@example.com instead of philip@contoso.com.

I know it's possible to do this because when I had e-mails forwarded using some web panel on a cheapo hosting company, it worked great. So how do I get postfix to retain the recipient address even though it's being forwarded to another address?

My config:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = mydomain.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = mx1.mydomain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = [smtp.mandrillapp.com]
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

To be clear, when I receive the e-mail at the forwarded address, I still want it to show the To: address as having the original recipient (@mydomain.com).

Comment: Two questions: [1] What's your current configuration? (please [edit] the question and post the output of `postconf -n` command) [2] Which address that do you want to keep? **MAIL TO: envelope recipient**  or  **To: headers in the message itself**?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you use this parameter

```
recipient_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical
```

to provide mail forwarding. By default [Canonical address mapping](http:///www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#canonical) will rewrite both header and envelope address. So, disable header rewriting, you have two options here

1. Configure `recipient_canonical_classes` so `recipient_canonical_maps` affects envelope address only.

   ```
   recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient
   ```
2. Use `virtual_alias_maps` that designed for envelope address mapping without touching header.

[The `virtual_alias_maps` option is preferred](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.mail.postfix.user/231519) in this case as you can use it to perform one-to-many mapping. Parameter `recipient_canonical_maps` only support one-to-one mapping.

Comment: Let me explain what I did. First, I started with virtual_alias_maps, but then I saw repeated warning not to use that with the same domain as my primary domain. In any case, it had the same problem. Next I moved everything to the standard alias_maps and it didn't change anything. Next I tried adding the recipient_canonical_maps, but that didn't change anything either. I meant to remove the recipient_canonical_maps listing in any case, and I certainly need one-to-many mapping. So is there a way to retain the recipient address using the standard alias_maps?

Comment: Ah, looks like the appropriate config is `alias_maps`, not virtual_alias_maps. Remember that alias_maps syntax is bit different with both virtual_alias_maps and recipient_canonical_maps. Anyway can you share alias_maps file entry and the exact error message in mail.log?